# I have a Parse Error that I cannot get my head around

Tags: parsing

As seen in the code below, the beginning of this code is showing some errors. It seems that it isn't expecting the private variables.

Any suggestions? It's probably REALLY simple.

```
class Database { <--ERROR HERE


    private db_host = 'localhost'; <--ERROR HERE
    private db_user = 'root'; <--ERROR HERE
    private db_pass = 'mysql89'; <--ERROR HERE
    private db_name = 'faceshit'; <--ERROR HERE


public function connect() { ... REST OF CODE IS FINE
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the error is due to something before `class Database {`? Show the exact error and specify what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $ symbol is missing before your variable names :

```php
private $db_host = 'localhost';
private $db_user = 'root';
private $db_pass = 'mysql89';
private $db_name = 'faceshit';
```